# Can i set default Object value in select

Tags: reactjs

[image]

```js
const currencies = [
  {
    value: "USD",
    label: "$",
    name: "Dollar"
  },
  {
    value: "EUR",
    label: "€",
    name: "Euro"
  }
];

export default function MultilineTextFields() {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState({ 
    label: "€", 
    value: "EUR",
    name: "Euro" 
  });

  const handleChange = event => {
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
      {console.log(currency)}
      <div>
        <TextField
          select
          value={currency}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {currencies.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I can't set Object value in Select. If `<MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>` not problem, But I need some value in Object for output. I must `value={option}` for print `{currency.name}` in some fields.

Comment: Please postcode in your question instead of images

Comment: if you want to set, normally you need state and an onChange function to set the state

Comment: Are you trying to set a default (selected) value for a select element?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a `defaultValue` prop for the wrapping "select" element/component, and specify a non-object value to the "option".

```
<TextField
  id="standard-select-currency"
  select
  label="Select"
  value={currency}
  onChange={handleChange}
  helperText="Please select your currency"
  defaultValue="EUR"
>
  {currencies.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

[image: Edit gallant-goodall-gf98l]